# How to set a cache-control header based on presence of query parameter?

Tags: cache, httpd

I'm trying to set a header for cache-control on certain resouces where we've used query string parameters to set revision codes... for example:
/foo/bar/resource1.js?v20140710

This is from the httpd.conf file

```
#set revision files far future
<LocationMatch "^.*\?v\d{8}$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31535999, public"
</LocationMatch>
```

This doesn't appear to work (cache control not set).  I'm wondering if I can't test the querystring in the LocationMatch?  Alternatives?

I saw a suggestion to use a rewrite rule... 
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^.*\?v\d{8}$"

But I'm not sure how to set the header out of the rewriterule?

So two questions... can i directly match the GET request based  on the query string (and how)?   And if not, how else to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overcomplicating... (and a little ignorant of Apache conf expressions).
This did it.

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /v\d{8}$/">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31535999, public"
</If>
```